# How to query a relationship through a relationship collection

Tags: php, laravel

I have a user and a department, a user can belong to many departments. I'm trying to define a scope on the user model to only show users of departments that the current user is a part of:

```
public function scopeVisible($query) {
    $user = Auth::user();

    return $user->departments()->users();
}
```

I've looked at the documentation and can't seem to find a way to do this.

I tried mapping but got strange errors where a method call would be on a query builder instead of a collection even though the object is a collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships) says you can use `whereHas` to add customized constraints for more specific queries:

> If you need even more power, you may use the whereHas and orWhereHas
>   methods to put "where" conditions on your has queries. These methods
>   allow you to add customized constraints to a relationship constraint.

Then this should work:

```
public function scopeVisible($query) {
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    return $query->whereHas('departaments', function($query) use ($user_id) {
      $query->where('user_id', '=', $user_id);
    });
}
```

The error you are getting about "*the method call must be on a query builder instead of a collection*" it's because on your code you are returning the result of `$user->departments()->users()`, which is a collection of Departments, you should return the query builder instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Perhaps add an explanation so people visiting this question can get a better idea of what is going on in your code?

Comment: @SebastianOlsen on the way ;)